# if field_id is empty then left outer join x, else left outer join y

Tags: if-statement, left-join

I hope someone can help me with this SQL-topic...
I would like to create a left outer join to a certain table if 'field1_id' is not null. If 'field1_id' is null, I would like to create a left outer join to an other table.

Is this possible ?